# Spring @Cacheable not working - MultiThreading

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, executorservice, spring-cache

I have a spring batch where it executes multiple threads using executor service. All threads access below method. I tried to cache the method using @Cacheable. But it is not working. Everythread executes this method without caching. I found that out using sysouts. Much worse, even the same thread goes inside the method multiple times without caching (inside for loop).

Can you please tell me what is it im doing wrong here.

```
   @Cacheable(key="#userID",sync=true)
      public String getPassword(String userID) throws Exceptions{

          
    logger.info("cache not working");   

    SecurityTokenClientResponse password=client.getPassword(req, true, notify.getEnv());
    
    byte[] encryptedPassword=password.getPasswordByteArray();
    
    if (encryptedPassword!=null)
    {
                try {
                    return retrieveCreds(client, encryptedPassword);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                
    
    }else {
    
    password.getBusinessError();
    
    
    }
    
    return null;
    
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `synchronized` with your method ?

Comment: How and from where are you calling the `getPassword` method and which cache are you using? Are you sure you are using a cache or a NOOP cache (no-caching)?

Comment: provide the calling code.

Answer (score 4):

To make Spring Caching work, make sure you have:

- use `@EnableCaching`
- create a CacheManager bean
- tell your method which cache it should use:  `@Cacheable(cacheNames = "name of your cache")`

Example :

```
@Bean
public SimpleCacheManager simpleCacheManager() {
    SimpleCacheManager simpleCacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
    simpleCacheManager.setCaches(Collections.singletonList(new ConcurrentMapCache("myCacheName")));
    return simpleCacheManager;
}
```

And:

```
@Cacheable(key="#userID",sync=true, cacheNames ="myCacheName")
public String getPassword(String userID) throws Exceptions
```